# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ajax, http, http-headers, cors, put

I have three ajax calls (POST, GET and PUT), all preceded by a preflight request (OPTIONS). The POST call creates a user, the GET call reads the user and the PUT call modifies this user. They are all chained calls with .then(). All the requests are cross-domain and the server has implemented CORS. All requests are made from the same origin to the same server (all to the same resource), but only the PUT request provoke the error in the title. The filter in the back-end to modify the header is the same for all requests (POST, GET, PUT, DELETE), so I really don't know why the request is cancelled. Also, the preflight request which is there to confirm that the server allows the PUT request to go through has no problem and comes back with a favorable access-control-allow-origin...

I also noticed that Chrome cancels the PUT request (maybe because the origin is not allowed)
[image]

Hopefuly you can help me :D

Comment: Do the header settings for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` also contain `PUT`?

Comment: Shot in the dark: The response doesn't have an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  Have a look at your response headers for the PUT request as reported by a proxy and post them here.

Comment: The PUT request has no response, as it is cancelled by Chrome. The PUT's preflight request does have a favorable Acess-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Your PUT response also needs an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  You are clearly missing this from your response.

Comment: @RayNicholus There is no response, it gets cancelled by Chrome, with the error message in the console.

Comment: No, Chrome is not canceling the request, it may just appear that way.  The issue is in your server code, as I have mentioned.

Comment: But I am using the same code for all the requests...and only this one fails.

Comment: I suggest you setup a proxy and have a closer look at the requests and responses.  This will make the cause of the problem more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the request is made, but the execution of the (probably PHP) script fails due to some error before the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set.